# I need to use a Vertical tab with dynamic content in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I am using a Vertical Tab in my code

```
VerticalTabs( tabsWidth: 200, new Text("Tab 1"), Text("Tab 2"), Text("Tab 3"), contents: <Widget>
[

 Container(
            child: MultiCheckboxes(
            values: studentsMap,
            controller: _studentsController,
           ))
])
```

My studentsMap is an asynchronous call to retrieve a list of all students in the class. As this is an asynchronous call I would like to call the CircularProgressBar till the data loads. However, as the Vertical tab is built only once I am unable to click on "Tab 2" for example and view a circularprogressbar in the contents and then view the data once the asynchronous call is complete.Can I use the same widget for this data or do I need to use another widget that can handle asynchronous data ?

Comment: Are you using [vertical_tabs](https://pub.dev/packages/vertical_tabs#-readme-tab-) library? Why can't you just wrap it inside [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and show `ProgressIndicator` while `connectionState` is waiting and `VerticalTabs` when its done

Comment: Hi @ShababbKarim Yes, I am using the vertical_tabs  library.

Comment: What is the name of the async method call? Can you add that too if the code snippet is not too big

Comment: @ShababbKarim Your futurebuilder worked like a charm. thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks. Added it to the answer. If it helped you then mark it as accepted please.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `VerticalTabs` inside [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and show [ProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ProgressIndicator-class.html) while `connectionState` is waiting and show the `VerticalTabs` when the future is done completing.

Example of how `FutureBuilder` works is [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html#shortSnippetButton).